# Why do tables in R with conditions on the presented variable perform so strange?

Tags: r

I am using the following code:

```
a <- c(1,2,2,1,NA,1,NA,NA,2,1,1,NA)
b <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,NA,1,1,1,NA,1)
test <- data.frame(a,b)

table(test$a[test$b == 0], useNA = "ifany")
table(test$a[test$b == 0 & !is.na(test$b)], useNA = "ifany")
```

I expected the same output as the condition `test$b == 0` already includes the condition `!is.na(test$b)`. If test$b is 0, it cannot be NA.

But this is my Output:

```
> table(test$a[test$b == 0], useNA = "ifany")

   1    2 <NA> 
   3    2    3 
> table(test$a[test$b == 0 & !is.na(test$b)], useNA = "ifany")

   1    2 <NA> 
   3    2    1
```

So you have to add the `!is.na(test$b)`to get the correct results. Not only that, I don't understand the results of the first table at all. Even if R just added the cases of a where b is NA (which still would be strange), it should be four times one, two times two and two times NA, not three times one, two times two and three times NA.

Can anybody explain this strange table and how to bypass these unnecessarily long conditional statements?

Comment: lookup 3-valued logic

Comment: Compare `test$b == 0` and `test$b %in% 0`. Maybe you want to `match` with zero which is what the latter does.

Comment: @HongOoi could your elaborate?